# Creating custom week number in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with ID and Date columns.

**Table A:**

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | 2019-10-29 |
| 24 | 2019-10-30 |
| 24 | 2019-10-31 |
| ..... | .... |

I need to add a column called "Week_Num" such that:

1. If there is a new "ID" and the first date begins on a Tuesday (eg: 29th Oct,2019 in ID 24 is Tuesday) then the week will start with 1
2. Week will always end on Saturday irrespective of whether 7 days are over or not with only one exception (see point 3)
3. If there is a new "ID" and the first date begins before Tuesday (eg: 25th Oct,2020 in ID 25 is Sunday) then the week will start with 0 and once it reaches Tuesday the week_num will become 1.

**Expected Output:**

| ID | Date | Day_Of_Week | Week_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 2019-10-29 | Tue | 1 |
| 24 | 2019-10-30 | Wed | 1 |
| 24 | 2019-10-31 | Thur | 1 |
| 24 | 2019-11-01 | Fri | 1 |
| 24 | 2019-11-02 | Sat | 1 |
| 24 | 2019-11-03 | Sun | 2 |
| 24 | 2019-11-04 | Mon | 2 |
| 24 | 2019-11-05 | Tues | 2 |
| 24 | 2019-11-06 | Wed | 2 |
| 24 | 2019-11-07 | Thurs | 2 |
| 24 | 2019-11-08 | Fri | 2 |
| 24 | 2019-11-09 | Sat | 2 |
| 24 | .......... | . | .. |
| 24 | 2020-03-14 | . | .. |
| 25 | 2020-10-25 | Sun | 0 |
| 25 | 2020-10-26 | Mon | 0 |
| 25 | 2020-10-27 | Tue | 1 |
| 25 | 2020-10-28 | Wed | 1 |
| 25 | 2020-10-29 | Thur | 1 |
| 25 | 2020-10-30 | Fri | 1 |
| 25 | 2020-10-31 | Sat | 1 |

What I have so far:

```
select 
distinct ID,min(Date) over (partition by ID order by date) as firstTuesdayOfSeason
from
TableA
group by ID,Date
having datepart(weekday,Date)=3
```

which gets the first Tuesday for every new ID and gives the following output:

| ID | firstTuesdayOfSeason |
| --- | --- |
| 24 | 2019-10-29 |
| 25 | 2020-10-27 |

I was thinking of joining this table with the Table A (the one with ID, Date as columns) but I don't know how to implement the weird Saturday logic.

Comment: Why not just use ISO week-numbers and then add an offset?

Comment: You must make sure that you're presenting the correct sample data and/or expected output. Currently your expected output is showing the same `Date` for `ID` in it's last 5 rows before the row of `|  24  | ..... | `.

Comment: What if the date start is on days other than Sunday, Monday or Tuesday? Maybe on Thursday? or Saturday?

Comment: The business logic as of now is that the date will always start on Tuesday with few exceptions where it can start on Sunday.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean that when the actual date starts on Wednesday, Thursday,  Friday or Saturday, it will always take the Tuesday before that as the start date; assigned as week 1.. and when the actual date starts on Sunday or Monday, it will take Sunday as the start date but assigned with week 0 until it reach the next Tuesday where it will become week 1, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

Find min-date, offset to Tuesday for each ID, and calculate using date-diff for each row against the min-date

```
select a.ID, a.Date, weekday(a.Date), greatest(0, 1 + floor((datediff(a.Date, b.since) - b.off) / 7)) week_num
from TableA a 
join (
  select ID, min(Date) As since, (case when weekday(min(Date)) > 1 then 8 - weekday(min(Date)) else 1 - weekday(min(Date)) end) off
  from TableA
  group by ID
) b ON a.ID = b.ID
order by a.ID, a.Date
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=657c96465338a398ced73bc256ff92c0